# SQL Server source control

Tags: sql-server, version-control

I'm planning to use source control for SQL Server database. I have different versions of SQL Server (2005 and 2008) running on different machines (Windows 2003 and 2008). I looked up about source control and found out 2 options.

- http://nobhillsoft.com/Randolph.aspx
- http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

So I was just wondering if someone have experience with them and suggest me which one would be good out of these or any other better option?

Thanks!

Comment: What specifically are you trying to contain in source control? Stored procedures, queries, table definitions, views....?

Comment: +1 djdanlib.  @Deepak Team Foundation Server has source control however it all depends on exactly what you are trying to version/protect.

Comment: @djdanlib - i wanted to use source control for table defs, queries, stored proc, view and if possible for data also.

Comment: i'll look into team foundation server, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you may be approaching something here from the wrong angle. If you try to revert a change to the table structure, but the table has been populated with data fitting the new table structure, what happens? It's more complex than maintaining plaintext diffs. I encourage you to really look at the idea and see if you can accomplish this another way, and document your database design as completely as possible every time you need to change it.

That being said, here are some more ideas.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic753558-361-1.aspx

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic635185-145-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I compare all these options and going with Red-gate source control and data source solution. Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use your current version control system if it's suitable for you to store only installation SQL script of a database.

1. Use SSMS to produce installation script: right-click on desired databased, select Tasks -> Generate Scripts... Script Wizard will start and help you to script any objects you need in the database including data. Save this script under your version control system since it's text file.
2. Use this database installation script to reproduce the database at desired location and environment.